# Google Apps Script web editor crashing on open

Tags: google-apps-script

For first few days of scriptig it has worked fine.

But yesterday it has stop working. Every time I open editor no code is visible and editor show generic error message "occurred unexcepted error". See screenshot.

After testing and research I found some facts

- problem occures on both my google account (company and personal)
- problem occures on every document (even if I open script editor for first time on this document)
- problem occures on both my PC on chrome
- clear chrome cache didnt help
- in FF editor is working fine

Sorry for screen in czech, but I am not able change language becouse all gui is disabled.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybJjT.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Stack Overflow is not for reporting problems with the Apps Script code editor.  Please post your experience to the [Link to Apps Script community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: You might to add the **google-apps-script-editor** tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can change language in browser preferences.
Which web browser are you using ? Have you try an over one ?